# Doubts on SP infrastructure

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, iis, infrastructure

My client has 2 WFEs. I have seen that the web applications and sites that I create in 1 server are mirrored in another server. But if I try to access sites under those web apps from another wfe using that wfe url, they don't load even though they are present. They typically show an unauthorized error or show the login popup 3 times before showing unauthorized. Why does this happen? Also, if a server goes down, can I use another wfe to open the same site? How do I set this up? I need to do it for an existing web application.

Comment: Couple of questions, What Authnetication you are using for the web app? are you using the DNS or server name and port numbers?

Comment: Claims with Windows authentication and server name and port numbers.

Comment: So no Kerberos? also Did you configure the Object cahce(super user and super reader)

Comment: Nope. No Kerberos. Not sure what those are. Pretty much a noob when it comes to infrastructure part. Could you pls explain it to me?

Comment: can you login on 2nd server and access the site using server name and port number....here is object cache link https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff758656.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I checked central admin as suggested in link. No, we haven't configured any super user or reader for object cache. Ntauthority\localservice and two other accounts all have full read permissions.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE any ideas about this?